# Удалять из списка gridView

Tags: java, android, gridview

Есть активити GridView, куда добавляю сначала свои элементы, а потом пробую их удалить.
Студия ошибок не выдаёт, но и не удаляет элементы, можете подсказать что в моём коде не так?
код адаптера

```
 public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PersonItems> {

PersonItems personItems;

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView member_name;
    ImageView profile_pic;
}

public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<PersonItems> users) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item, users);
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // ViewHolder буферизирует оценку различных полей шаблона элемента

    personItems = getItem(position);

    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    // Очищает сущетсвующий шаблон, если параметр задан
    // Работает только если базовый шаблон для всех классов один и тот же
    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        viewHolder.member_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.member_name);
        viewHolder.profile_pic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
    viewHolder.member_name.setText(personItems.name);
    viewHolder.profile_pic.setImageResource(setImage());

    Button buttonDelete = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonDelete);
    buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            personItems.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

public int setImage() {
    switch (personItems.getName()) {
        case Names.teso:
            return R.drawable.teso;
        case Names.test:
            return R.drawable.test;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

}

Comment: в вашем коде на первый взгляд все правильно. Вы уверены, что нажатия на кнопку buttonDelete срабатывают? может у вас кроме этого установлен onItemClickListener, и они конфликтуют?

Comment: Кроме того, я не уверен, что адаптер ссылается на тот же список personItems. Покажите весь код адаптера

Comment: @metalurgus в том то и дело что не срабатывают, просто жму на кнопку и ничего, хотя по идее должно.

Comment: скорее всего, вам нужно добавить в xml тэг вашей кнопки `android:clickable="true"`

Comment: @СергейГрушин увы нет(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал сделать следующее:

1. Унаследуйтесь от BaseAdapter
2. Добавьте `Activity activity;`, `ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();`
3. Создайте конструктор

`public CustomAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Person> persons) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.persons = persons;
    }`

4. Имплеменируйте методы примерно следующим образом:

   @Override
   public int getCount() {
       return persons.size();
   }

   @Override
   public Object getItem(int i) {
       return persons.get(i);
   }

   @Override
   public long getItemId(int i) {
       return 0;
   }

Ну и собственно Ваш метод удаления

```
public void onClick(View view) {
            persons.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Должен работать корректно (т.к Вы использовали `setTag`/`getTag`).

Answer (score 2):

Вы на самом деле ничего не удаляете.  `personItems.remove(position);` ничего не удаляет из адаптера. У адаптера есть свой собственный метод `remove(object)`, который удалит нужный объект. В вашем случае использовать так:

```
 public void onClick(View view) {
    remove(personItems);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Супер, спасибо, только он удаляет не выбранный элемент, а последний который добавили(

Comment: тогда теряется смысл этой строчки personItems = getItem(position); именно поэтому я и использовал в принципе  position

Comment: @Inkognito, попробуйте тогда `remove(getItem(position))`

Answer (score 0):

1. Удаляете из списка 
   list.remove(position);
2. Оповещаете адаптер
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();